# When is the scalar product of two normalizable 4-vectors, normalizable?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

The specific dilemma that I'm encountering is as follows: Let $n_\alpha$ denote the normal to a hypersurface $\Sigma$. Let $u_\mu$ denote the velocity of a particle randomly crossing $\Sigma$. They satisfy,
$$n^\mu n_\mu = \pm 1$$
and 
$$u^\mu u_\mu = -1$$

Given these two, what can we say about the normalisability of the scalar product
$n^\mu u_\mu$ (assuming it doesn't vanish everywhere), and what are the conditions ?

Although they seem unconnected, I can't help but think that we can in general normalise $n^\mu u_\mu$. Is this correct ? Can someone suggest something to help clarify? I didn't find something relevant online, so references are also welcome.

Comment: What does normalizability of the scalar product of two vectors mean?

Comment: Ok.I should've defined that. I meant to ask if and when we can write $n^\mu u_\mu = \pm 1$ while satisfying the 2 given conditions

Comment: There's no operation you can do: either $|n^\mu u_\mu|$ is 1, or it isn't. Am I understanding your question properly?

Comment: Naively speaking, I can consider $n'^\mu \rightarrow n^\mu + f^\mu$ such that $n'^\mu n'_\mu = \pm 1$ and obtain a family of $f^\mu$ satisfying some conditions. Same for $u^\mu$. Basically any transformation which leaves the scalar norm invariant is allowed. Using this class of transformations can we choose an $n'^\mu$ and a $u'^\mu$ such that their scalar product is normalised throughout.

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ meant to be a spacelike hypersurface?

Answer (score 0):

If two vectors are time-like, both satisfying $X^{\mu}X_{\mu} = -1$ then I think you can only safely say that there is frame in which $n^{\mu}$ and $u^{\mu}$ are proportional (there is a Lorentz transformation connecting them locally). Define $U^{\mu} = L^{\mu}_{\, \nu} u^{\nu},$ $N^{\mu} = (L')^{\mu}_{\, \nu} n^{\nu},$ then  $U^{\mu}N_{\mu} = -1$ if $L L' = 1.$ (for the opposite sign it would be an improper Lorentz transformation). Physically it would mean that there is an observer for which both velocities are the same.

Now, in the context of General Relativity if, for a given space-time, $n^{\mu}$ is a Killing vector field and if $u^{\mu}$ is a time-like hypersurface invariant vector field, then the space-time is static if they co-exist and are proportional (check D'Inverno or Ryder when discussing time-independent metrics).